# For any positive integer $n$, show that $\sum_{d|n}\sigma(d) = \sum_{d|n}(n/d)\tau(d)$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, summation, divisor-sum, multiplicative-function, divisor-counting-function

For any positive integer $n$, show that $\sum_{d|n}\sigma(d) = \sum_{d|n}(n/d)\tau(d)$

---

My try :

Left hand side :
$\begin{align} \sum_{d|p^k}\sigma (d) &= \sigma(p^0) + \sigma(p^1) + \sigma(p^2) + \cdots + \sigma(p^k) \\ &= \dfrac{p^{0+1}-1}{p-1} +  \dfrac{p^{1+1}-1}{p-1}  + \cdots +  \dfrac{p^{k+1}-1}{p-1}  \\&= \dfrac{1}{p-1}\left( (p + p^2 + \cdots + p^{k+1}) - (k+1)\right) \\&= \dfrac{1}{p-1}\left(\dfrac{p(p^{k+1}-1)}{p-1}- (k+1)\right) \\
\end{align}$

I'm not sure if I am in right path; this doesn't look simple. Any help ?

Comment: Reduce to the case of prime powers (as it looks like you've already done), then compute both sides of $n = p^k$. You don't need to compute a closed form for the left side directly; just count how many times each $p^r$ appears in the sum.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can reduce to prime powers to get the job done, but that doesn't get at the heart of the equality.

$$\sum_{d\mid n}\sigma(d)=\sum_{d\mid n}\sum_{r\mid d}r=\sum_{r\mid d\mid n}r=\cdots$$

Can you continue? For each $r\mid n$, how many times is $r$ a summand of the above sum?

Comment: Exactly! I have felt the same when working as all I was doing was just algebra. If I am understanding correctly, it seems in your method $n$ need not be a single prime power($p^k$) ?

Comment: and $r$ appears $\tau(d)*\tau(n)$ times i guess, not so sure sorry

Comment: Indeed, $n$ is an arbitrary natural number here. We sum an $r$ for each instance of $r\mid d\mid n$, in other words the number of $r$s is equal to the number of $d$s for which $r\mid d\mid n$, which is equals the number of divisors of $n/r$... can you proceed further from here? What does the sum look like at this point?

Comment: i see it now xD so the multiplier for each $r$ is $\tau(n/r)$ in the sum; for example, $r=n$ appears only once because $\tau(n/n) = 1$

Comment: how to switch from $r$'s to $d$'s ?

Comment: change of variables ($r\leftrightarrow\frac{n}{r}$): $~\sum\limits_{r\mid n}r\,\tau(\frac{n}{r})=\sum\limits_{r\mid n}\frac{n}{r}\tau(r)$

Comment: beautiful ! d is just a dummy variable is it !!! you deserve 1000 medals xD i feel much better about these notations now! thank you so much :)

Answer (score 6):

Define
the functions $N$ and $1$
by
$N(n)=n$ and $1(n)=1$
for all $n \in \mathbb{N}.$

An equivalent, but easier to write, solution is to note that the
function 
$\sum_{d|n}\sigma(d)$
is the Dirichlet convolution 
$\sigma\ast 1$
and thus the
definition $\sigma=N*1$
implies that 
$$\sigma*1=(N*1)*1=N*(1*1).$$
Now notice that $1*1$ is the classical divisor function $\tau$
and we therefore get
$$
\sigma*1=N*\tau,$$
which provides the required answer.

Answer (score 3):

looking at this intuitively, firstly we note that:
$$
\sum_{d|n}\sigma(d) = \sum_{d|n}(n/d)\tau(d) \\
=  \sum_{d|n} d\tau(n/d)
$$
so now we are summing the divisors $d$ of $n$, each divisor being counted with multiplicity $\tau(n/d)$. so you just have to persuade yourself that this multiplicity is appropriate.

but this is evident if we look at a particular $d$, since for  any integer  $m$ we have 
$$
dm | n  \Leftarrow \Rightarrow m | n/d
$$
in words there is a 1-1 correspondence between (a)  *multiples of $d$ which divide $n$*, and (b)  *divisors of $n/d$*