# Prove that $\sum \limits_{d|n}(n/d)\sigma(d) = \sum \limits_{d|n}d\tau(d)$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, summation, divisor-sum, multiplicative-function, divisor-counting-function

How can I prove:

$$\sum \limits_{d|n}(n/d)\sigma(d) = \sum \limits_{d|n}d\tau(d)?$$

Few observations :
Left side is a sum function and the right side is a number of divisors function. Both the sides are multiplicative. I don't want to start expanding like [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/909131/for-any-positive-integer-n-show-that-sum-dn-sigmad-sum-dnn-d-t). Appreciate any help on how to interpret the sums!

Comment: Do have a look at the Mobius Inversion Formula, it looks quite similar : http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%B6bius_inversion_formula

Comment: both sides are multiplicative functions. So it is enough to check the equality for prime powers

Comment: thank you ! mobius inversion formula in the exact next topic in this module. I'll go through it and see if it is easy to follow. I'm thinking if it is possible to interpret this without mobius -  by using $\tau $, $\sigma$ and multiplicative properties

Comment: How have you proved that both the sides of the function are multiplicative?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

$$\sum_{d\mid n} \frac{n}d \sigma(d) =\sum_{d_1\mid n}\frac{n}{d_1}\sum_{d_2\mid d_1} d_2 =  \sum_{d_2\mid d_1\mid n}\frac{n}{d_1/d_2}$$

$$\sum_{d\mid n} d\tau(d)= \sum_{d_3\mid n} d_3\sum_{d_4\mid d_3}1 = \sum_{d_4\mid d_3\mid n} d_3$$

Now, map $(d_1,d_2)$ to $(d_3,d_4)=(nd_2/d_1,n/d_1)$ and we see we have the same sums.

So, more generally, if $S_n=\{(d_1,d_2): d_2\mid d_1\mid n\}$ then the map $S_n\to S_n$ defined by $(d_1,d_2)\to\left(\frac{nd_2}{d_1},\frac n{d_1}\right)$ is a bijection.  Thus, for any function $f(m,n)$ of two natural numbers, we have that:

$$\sum_{(d_1,d_2)\in S_n} f(d_1,d_2)=\sum_{(d_1,d_2)\in S_n} f\left(\frac{nd_2}{d_1},\frac{n}{d_1}\right)$$

The above is just the case of $f(m,n)=m$.

Comment: thats brilliant! thank you so much :)

Comment: I was wrong about it being an ivolution. The square of this map is $(d_1,d_2)\to \left(\frac{n}{d_2},\frac{d_1}{d_2}\right)$, and the cub is the identity.)

Answer (score 5):

First we note that by definition we have

$$\sigma(d) = \sum_{d_1|d}d$$

$$\tau(d) = \sum_{d_1|d}1$$

Then by substituting these into each side of the equation we get

$$\sum_{d|n}\frac{n}{d}\sigma(d) = \sum_{d|n}\frac{n}{d} \sum_{d_1|d} d_1 = \sum_{d|n}\sum_{d_1|d} \frac{n}{d/d_1}= \sum_{\substack{n=de\\d=d_1d_2}}\frac{n}{d/d_1} = \sum_{n=d_1d_2e}\frac{n}{d_2} = \sum_{n = d_1d_2e} d_1e$$

$$\sum_{d|n}d\tau(d) = \sum_{d|n}d\sum_{d_1|d} 1 = \sum_{d|n} \sum_{d_1|d} d = \sum_{\substack{n = de\\ d = d_1d_2}} d = \sum_{n = d_1d_2e} d_1d_2$$

And we can see the last two sums are the same.

Answer (score 0):

Note that $\sigma=N*1$ and $\tau=1*1$ where "*" is the Dirichlet convolution and $N$ is the identical fucntion in positive integers. We have $$\sum_{d\mid n}{\frac{n}{d}\sigma\left(d\right)=N*\sigma}=N*\left(N*1\right)=\left(N*N\right)*1=\left(\sum_{d\mid n}{d\cdot\frac{n}{d}}\right)*1=\left(\sum_{d\mid n}n\right)*1$$ $$=\left(N\tau\right)*1=\sum_{d\mid n}{d\cdot\tau\left(d\right).}$$