# $\sum_{d|n} \sigma(d)=\sum_{d|n} \frac{n}{d}\tau(d)$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

The question is to show that:
$$\sum_{d|n} \sigma(d)=\sum_{d|n} \frac{n}{d}\tau(d)$$

I checked [For any positive integer $n$, show that $\sum_{d|n}\sigma(d) = \sum_{d|n}(n/d)\tau(d)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/909131)
And I understood what he was doing but I didn’t get how he concluded the result
Can someone explain?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure what you didn't understand so I will just prove it again here.

$$S=\sum_{d|n}\sigma(d)=\sum_{d|n}\sum_{q|d}q$$

So how many times does an integer $q$ appear in the sum? Each time $q$ divides one of the divisors on $n$. (Notice that $q$ is also a divisor of $n$) So our sum is equal to $$S=\sum_{d|n}d\cdot(\text{the number of divisors of }n\text{ which are divisible by }d)$$ So how mant divisors of $n$ are divisible by $d$? Well let such a divisor be $d\cdot k$. Then, $d\cdot k|n$ so $k|\frac{n}{d}$, so the number of divisors of $n$ that are divisible with $d$ is, in fact, the number of divisors of $\frac{n}{d}$, which gives us $$S=\sum_{d|n}d\cdot\tau\big(\frac{n}{d}\big)$$ which is what we wanted to prove.

Comment: thank you so much

Comment: It was my pleasure